# Drools - Re-use of rules via setFocus() - or other strategies?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

Basically I'm in a situation where I have dozens of agenda groups, mostly being executed separately from one another and all using different subsets of the same rules.

My current setup just involves a lot of copy/pasting of the rules:

```html
agenda-group "agenda_group_1"
rule "Rule_A"
rule "Rule_B"
rule "Rule_C"
rule "Rule_D"

agenda-group "agenda_group_2"
rule "Rule_A"
rule "Rule_C"
rule "Rule_D"
rule "Rule_E"
```

... and so on.

Invocation of agenda groups is controlled via a list from another service so I'm trying to keep those the same at the top level.

The idea I had was to re-use the rule implementations by following a "1-rule-per-agenda" pattern:

```html
agenda-group "agenda_group_1"
rule "agenda_group_1"
when
        x
then
        WorkingMemory workingMemory = drools.getWorkingMemory();
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_A");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_B");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_C");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_D");
end

agenda-group "agenda_group_2"
rule "agenda_group_2"
when
        x
then
        WorkingMemory workingMemory = drools.getWorkingMemory();
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_A");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_C");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_D");
        workingMemory.setFocus("Rule_E");
end
```

...and implement the rules in their own re-usable agenda group files.

I was wondering if this approach is generally advisable for my needs? I have a lot of rules (and a lot of re-use) and performance is an important consideration for me.

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way to accomplish re-using rules so if anyone could point me to relevant documentation or examples that would be great.

Given that I'm receiving a fixed list of agenda groups to run, my options may be limited within drools though.

Thank you

Comment: Rule flow groups, possibly. But one-rule-per-group sounds like it will incur a crazy amount of overhead. You're only using the agenda group to trigger a subset of rules, so why not just write that into the rules' LHS?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.

`>You're only using the agenda group to trigger a subset of rules, so why not just write that into the rules' LHS?`

Could you expand on this? What would these rules be matching on in the LHS in this case?

Comment: What would they match against? I couldn't say since your example with what the triggers are in the agenda groups is totally value (`x`).